# Обработка исключений(Ошибок) Node JS+Express JS

Tags: node.js, express, ecmascript-6

Подскажите каким образом можно реализовать обработку ошибок.
Сейчас для перехвата ошибки используется конструкция try...catch

```
export const RegistrationAction = async (request, response, next) => {
  try {
    return response.json(request.body);
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }
};
```

Проблема в том что не удобно везде писать данную конструкции.

Возможно ли глобально реализовать перехват исключений для возможности избежать повторения try...catch?

Comment: Если кратко, то так не получится. в try catch вы можете заложить для каждой функции альтернативное поведение(в catch). Глобавльный перехват ошибок уже и так реализован, он останавливает процесс node и выводит ошибку :)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ =)